# How to convert from utf8 to unicode in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, encoding

I have a string encoded in utf 8, I want to convert it to unicode, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onload(Event):void
{
RLDATA = myLoader.data.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);
RLDATA.pop();
for (var i:int=0; i<RLDATA.length; i++){
var rowArray:Array = RLDATA[i].split(",");
RLDATA[i] = { Team_name: rowArray[0], team_id: rowArray[1], Player_name:
rowArray[2],Player_id: rowArray[3], player_rating_and_position: rowArray[4], tier:
rowArray[5],staminia: rowArray[6],speed: rowArray[7],
acceleration: rowArray[8],agility: rowArray[9], ball_handling: rowArray[10],   
tackle_ability: rowArray[11],break_tackle: rowArray[12], unknown: rowArray[13],  
jersey_position_number: rowArray[14]};

}
RLDATA.shift();
sheet.dataProvider = new DataProvider(RLDATA);

}


function update(event:MouseEvent):void {
for (var c:Number = 0; c < sheet.length - 1; c++) {  

CSV += sheet.getItemAt(c).Team_name + "," + sheet.getItemAt(c).team_id+ "," +   
sheet.getItemAt(c).Player_name+ "," + sheet.getItemAt(c).Player_id+ "," +   
sheet.getItemAt(c).player_rating_and_position+ "," + sheet.getItemAt(c).tier+ "," +
sheet.getItemAt(c).staminia+ "," + sheet.getItemAt(c).speed
+ "," + sheet.getItemAt(c).acceleration+ "," + sheet.getItemAt(c).agility+ "," +  
sheet.getItemAt(c).ball_handling+ "," + sheet.getItemAt(c).tackle_ability+ "," +
sheet.getItemAt(c).break_tackle+ "," + sheet.getItemAt(c).unknown+ "," +         
sheet.getItemAt(c).jersey_position_number+"\r\n" ;

}

}


function Writefile(event:MouseEvent) {
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeUTFBytes(CSV);
file.save(bytes,"test.csv");
}
```

The above I used to populate a data grid known as "sheet" from a CVS files that was a list of games stats for the xbox game/Pc Rugby league.
Above using the Split method, if you pasted some code some one could help you exactly what you were after hope this helps

Like i suggested if you have problems understanding this than google the SPLIT method, as the above code was written for my project not yours but you should be able to rework it for your project.

Comment: I have checked Google, found absolutely nothing.

Comment: http://ffiles.com/flash/web_applications_and_data/cvs_game_datagrid_3559.html?message=New%20listing%20added&message_type=success

Comment: @parale The user who posted this question doesn't have enough rep to vote or downvote.  I don't know who downvoted this, though, but the "check Google" response is the most likely cause.  It is not considered appropriate on this site to tell people to "Go Search" for the answer.

Comment: @parele: what the hell does this "answer" answer? You've shown how to read / write a csv using AS3. Not that OP's question is  clear either...

Comment: yes i have shown you how to manipulate a string into what ever you want split();

Comment: the text file i used was utf as well, CVS is irrelvent as it just consisted of commers

Comment: give us some detail to help you out instaed of a one lined question